# How do I rsync folders starting with a dot?

Tags: directory, rsync

I'm trying to sync a maildir directory, which some folders within this maildir directory contains directory starting with "dot"

```
.Archive/
.Sent Items/
```

I tried using the following

```
$ rsync -pogutr --exclude="." --exclude=".." .*  /home/folder1/mail/domain/user1/ /home/folder2/mail/domain --progress
$ rsync -pogutr --exclude="../" /home/folder1/mail/domain/user1/.*  /home/folder2/mail/domain/ --progress
$ rsync -pogutr --include=".*" /home/folder1/mail/domain/user1  /home/folder2/mail/domain/ --progress
```

All of which will sync other sub-directories within `/home/folder1/mail/domain/` into the `/home/folder2/mail/domain/user1/` directory.

For example, if `/home/folder1/mail/domain/` contains sub-directory of user1, user2 and user3. Then all the contents of user1, user2 and user3 will be in the `/home/folder2/mail/domain/user1/` directory

Answer (score 0):

I faked a mail directory with some dot folders containing files and it synced correctly by default.

```
$ rsync --recursive --verbose maildir/ maildir-backup
sending incremental file list
created directory maildir-backup
./
.Archive/
.Archive/1
.Archive/2
.Archive/3
.Sent Items/
.Sent Items/bar
.Sent Items/baz
.Sent Items/foo

sent 481 bytes  received 182 bytes  1,326.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

I even tried the extra flags you were using (preserve owner, group, times, permissions, etc.)

```
$ rsync -pogutr --verbose maildir/ maildir-backup
sending incremental file list
created directory maildir-backup
./
.Archive/
.Archive/1
.Archive/2
.Archive/3
.Sent Items/
.Sent Items/bar
.Sent Items/baz
.Sent Items/foo

sent 497 bytes  received 182 bytes  452.67 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

You just don't want to or need to exclude "this" folder or the parent. These are not included in any paths.

```
--exclude="." --exclude=".."
```

Answer (score 0):

use 2 rsync commands: 1 normal and 1 for the dot folders. And specify the dot and escape it.
I used it for migration to docker-poste and ran this on my docker host:

```
rsync -e ssh -v -r -u root@10.10.0.7:/home/benny/Maildir/* /mnt/user/docker/poste/data/domains/example.com/benny/Maildir/
rsync -e ssh -v -r -u root@10.10.0.7:/home/benny/Maildir/\.* /mnt/user/docker/poste/data/domains/example.com/benny/Maildir/
```

Answer (score -2):

Try using [unison](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/) instead of rsync. In addition, it'll sync faster.

Comment: http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/unison/status.html

Unison is no longer under active development as a research project.